# One istio-ingressgateway and multiple TLS gateways

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

**Brief of the problem**:

- If I try to attach multiple TLS gateways (using the same certificate)
  to one ingressgateway, only one TLS will work. (The last applied)
- Attaching multiple non-TLS gateways to the same ingressgateway works ok.

**Error messages**:

Domain 1 (ok):

```
✗ curl -I https://integration.domain.com
HTTP/2 200 
server: envoy
[...]
```

Domain 2 (bad):

```
✗ curl -vI https://staging.domain.com    
* Rebuilt URL to: https://staging.domain.com/
*   Trying 35.205.120.133...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to staging.domain.com (35.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to staging.domain.com:443 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to staging.domain.com:443
```

**Facts**:

I have a wildcard TLS cert (lets say '*.domain.com') I've put in a secret with:

```
kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls istio-ingressgateway-certs --key tls.key --cert tls.crt
```

I have the default istio-ingressgateway attached to a static IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
  labels:
    chart: gateways-1.0.0
    release: istio
    heritage: Tiller
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: "35.x.x.x"
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
[...]
```

Then I have two gateways in different namespaces, for two domains included on the TLS wildcard (staging.domain.com, integration.domain.com):

staging:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: domain-web-gateway
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "staging.domain.com"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "staging.domain.com"
```

integration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: domain-web-gateway
  namespace: integration
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "integration.domain.com"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "integration.domain.com"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same name (https) for port 443 in two Gateways managed by the same workload (selector). They need to have unique names. This restriction is documented [here](https://preliminary.istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/deploy-guidelines/#configuring-multiple-tls-hosts-in-a-gateway).

You can fix it by just changing the name of your second Gateway, for example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: domain-web-gateway
  namespace: integration
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-integration
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "integration.domain.com"
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "integration.domain.com"
```

Comment: Ouh! Didn't know the 'preliminary' Istio section. Seems like docs are evolving quite quickly this days and sometimes lack some coherence (or are conflicting or outdated) I'll test this now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the docs are continuously evolving. preliminary.istio.io always contains the latest doc, which will move to istio.io at the next release. The doc that I referenced was also recently added to istio.io (https://istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/deploy-guidelines/#configuring-multiple-tls-hosts-in-a-gateway), but I referenced the preliminary version because I think it is more clearly explained there.

Comment: I'm getting the suspicion that you can't use '-' on port names.  When I named the ports as staging-https and integration-https I got this nasty error:

2018-10-10T13:40:01.856397Z error buildGatewayRoutes: could not find server for routeName https.443.staging-https, have map[http.80:[port:<number:80 protocol:"HTTP" name:"http" > hosts:"integration.domain.com"  port:<number:80 protocol:"HTTP" name:"http" > hosts:"staging.domain.com" ]]

Comment: But now I used 'httpsint' and 'httpssec' and everything is good :)

Comment: @FrankB In fact, I am curious about the behavior when I have multi TLS gateway enabled at the same time. If i enable two TLS gateway with same port but targeting different hostname, when a connection is coming, will it try to validate the SSL in the first option, and try to match the hostname? How about when the first match failed with match condition, and will it start to match with the second gateway TLS context and hostname? Does it mean multiple TLS handshake or something?

Comment: If the server has a TLS certificate matching the incoming request, it uses the gateway configured with that certificate. You need to be careful with wildcard certificates which can cause browser problems, but otherwise it's straightforward. https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-multiple-hosts https://preliminary.istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/deploy-guidelines/#browser-problem-when-multiple-gateways-configured-with-same-tls-certificate

Comment: @FrankB
I ran into similar problem in accessing different services in same browser. Because I use a wildcard certificate. Can you point me to the details why it happens and workaround if any ?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: @singh I think this is the issue you are having: https://istio.io/docs/ops/troubleshooting/network-issues/#404-errors-occur-when-multiple-gateways-configured-with-same-tls-certificate